# Ativando som em video background página html

Tags: javascript, css, html5, html5-video

tenho uma dúvida , parece simples, e acredito que seja: tenho um vídeo que utilizo como background, e o mesmo está com o atributo "mute" para rodar nos navegadores, mas quero disponibilizar um botão para o usuário  ativar o som.
Mas já tentei de várias formas ativar o som através de javascript, mas.... até agora....
Quem já passou por esta, e puder ajudar...

Segue o código abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var vid=document.getElementById("audio");
function aumentasom() {
    vid.volume+=0.2;
    }
</script>
```

X
    S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara eu consegui resolver aqui em partes. Não sei se existe alguma forma 100% segura de resolver isso, pois por questões de preferencia do usuário, UX e até segurança, em vídeos com Som o Autoplay não costuma funcionar.

O que eu fiz foi colocar `autoplay` e `muted` no vídeo, e depois em uma função `setTimeout()` eu removo o atributo `muted`, porem eventualmente vc pode ter esse erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja mais: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

***Esse erro ocorre apenas no Chrome. No FireFox e no Edge o áudio aparece mesmo sem interação do usuário.*** *(no Safari não sei dizer, nem em browsers mobile, nã tenho um ambiente de teste para isso)*

Mas de qq forma aqui tem um exemplo que pode funcionar ai e vale a pena vc testar.

***Atenção no Chrome:***
 **Repare que ao clicar em executar abaixo, se vc NÃO fizer nenhuma interação na página, seja clicando em algum lugar, dando *scroll* ou qq outra coisa o vídeo vai dar o erro descrito acima e vai se pausar.** Mas se houver qq interação na página o `muted` vai ser removido e o vídeo começa a ter áudio depois de 2000ms. Então esse código só funciona se o user clicar em algo, arrastar algo, escrever algo o fizer *scroll* na página dentro desse intervalo de 2 segundo, ou então o vídeo vai se pausar.

**OBS:** *Scroll* com a `mouse wheel` não vai ser uma interação "suficiente" para evitar o pousamento do vídeo, vc vai precisar *scrollar* com o *scroll* da janela clicando...

```js
const vid = document.getElementById('vv');

setTimeout(
    function () {
        vid.muted = false;
    }
, 2000);
```

```html
<br>
<br><input type="text" name="" id="">
<br><input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
<br>
<video id="vv" muted width="320" height="240" autoplay>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo....

Comment: @JosildoOliveira se deu certo considere marcar a Resposta como aceita clicando nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das Setinhas ao lado da minha resposta. Valeu a força, sucesso!