# O atributo "autoplay" não inicia o áudio por quê?

Tags: html, html5-audio

Estou criando uma página onde preciso reproduzir um som automaticamente como background em um loop infinito. O problema é que mesmo usando o atributo `autoplay`, o áudio não inicia.

Veja abaixo o meu código:

```html
<audio controls autoplay loop>
    <source src="main_sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

Estou utilizando o navegador `Chrome 81.0.4044.92` e também testei no Internet Explorer. Em ambos os navegadores essa propriedade não está funcionando por quê ?

O que eu posso fazer para reproduzir o áudio automaticamente utilizando apenas HTML ?

Comment: Você precisa fornecer uma URL válida para o `src` do áudio. Você verificou isso?

Comment: Sim. O áudio reproduz se eu clicar no botão de play, mas ele não roda automaticamente com a propriedade `autoplay`.

Comment: Imagina vc entra em um site e do nada fica o som do Negão do P*rocão tocando automaticamente? Entendeu Pq não funciona? Eh uma quer ao de privacidade tbm aqui tem uns detalhes para vídeo, mas eh praticamente a mesma coisa pra áudio https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412109/ativando-som-em-video-background-p%c3%a1gina-html/412124?r=SearchResults&s=1|20.1922#412124

Comment: Não funcionou. Copiei o código da resposta tirando apenas os atributos `width` e `height` e o áudio ainda não inicia.

Comment: Não vai funcionar o que que fazer, o Chrome como acho que todos os outros navegadores modificaram sua política de reprodução automática tudo por uma melhor experiência do usuário como poder ler aqui: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Então como é possível existir sites em que uma música ou vídeo é reproduzido automaticamente ?

Answer (score -3):

Já tem 2 anos a pergunta. Encontrei por acaso. Segue uma solução:

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" src="main_sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```