# Como ativar autoplay com som em qualquer browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, html5-audio

Olá.

Estou elaborando um site e gostaria de que, ao abrir a página, um som de fundo começasse a tocar automaticamente.

No entanto, parece que a Google andou dando umas censuradas em qualquer coisa que traga autoplay e som ao mesmo tempo. Ou seja, não é mais possível pelos modos tradicionais ter um play automático de vídeos com som e áudios.

Fazendo minhas pesquisas, já tentei uma renca de coisas. Já botei a prop muted e tentei removê-la com timeout no jQuery. Já tentei não usar a prop autoplay e acionar o método .play() ao carregar a página. Já tentei umas seis, sete coisas diferentes e o degenerado não toca automaticamente.

Até que cheguei [nesse link aqui](https://olafwempe.com/how-to-enable-audio-and-video-autoplay-with-sound-in-chrome-and-other-browsers-in-2019/), no qual é proposta uma solução usando iframe e **é mostrado um site em que isso realmente funciona**.

O meu problema é... eu baixei o áudio silence.mp3 daquele usuário. Eu utilizei basicamente o mesmo código, só mudando uma coisa ou outra de nomenclatura de id e tal. *E não funcionou.*

```
<iframe src="path/silence.mp3" type="audio/mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display:none"></iframe>
<audio id="bgsound" autoplay loop>
   <source src="path/natureza.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Não consigo compreender como o mesmo código funciona no site que o rapaz inseriu e não funciona no que eu estou criando. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz a respeito disso, por favor?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412109/ativando-som-em-video-background-p%c3%a1gina-html/412124#412124

Comment: Bom dia, Hugo. Eu já havia visto essa sua postagem. Se reparar, já até tentei uma solução semelhante, como descrevi no meu post. No entanto, reparei que, na sua solução, é necessário que o usuário interaja com a página, dependendo de um clique ou de um scroll que precisa necessariamente ser realizado pela janela do browser. O site que postei de exemplo consegue, com aquele trecho de código, ativar o som automaticamente sem depender de interação nenhuma. Seria um resultado mais satisfatório pro que preciso.

Comment: Chegou a tentar dar um ```play()``` no vídeo no ```onload()``` da página?

Comment: @NaryLuiz já. Já fiz teste com play() no onload(), já tentei também carregar o autoplay com muted e tentar remover o muted com um settimeout(). Nenhum deles funciona. Até agora, o que cheguei mais perto de fazer funcionar é tão confuso que eu nem sei explicar direito. Mas ainda assim, não funciona completamente.